# Android Back to first fragment in navigationdrawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have an app which has multiple fragments in NavigationDrawer.

Below is my code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        fragment = null;

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new GalleryFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new ContactFragment();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            int position = 0;
            fragment = new HomeFragment();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        } 



    }
```

What it basically does, it goes first to HomeFragment, when I wanna go to the other `fragment` MediaFragment and decide go back pressing the back button, I want to go to HomeFragment and when I want to close the app pressing again the back button it will now dismiss the app just like the gmail application. How can I achieve that? I'm having an issue using the code I put in my `onBackPressed()`. Whenever I go to other fragments the HomeFragment is the one that's showing. Any ideas? Your help will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**: Before when I was in `MediaFragment` and pressed the back button it automatically closes the app. It should not be like, but it should go to the `HomeFragment`, and when it is in `HomeFragment` and I click back button then it will close the app.

Comment: add the fragment to the backstack an remove them accordingly on backpressed

Comment: @Raghunandan can you some sample implementation of that? Thanks

Comment: `transaction.addToBackStack(null);` and to pop http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack()

Comment: I tried addToBackStack(null) but it's not doing what it is intended to

Comment: It will work coz you are adding it to the backstack and popping the same on backpressed. Read the docs http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of duplicating your code in onBackPressed, why not just keep track of the last position selected?

```
int selectedPosition = 0;

private void displayView(int position) {
    ... // All your current code
    selectedPosition = position;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (selectedPosition != 0) {
        displayView(0);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply add the fragment to backstack when you do the transaction as @Raghunandan said. See below code,

```
 if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit(); //Changed from fragmentManager to FragmentTrasaction 

        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); //this will add the fragment to backstack and hence pressing back will take to previous trasaction

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
```

Do not add the HomeFragment else when you press back you will see a blank page (or something like that) before you quit the app (you gotta press back again for that so avoid adding HomeFragment). Add all the fragment apart from it to the backstack and you will be able to proceed as you want. Also, when you load an Activity from a fragment it is maintained by application in backstack automatically so no need to worry about it.

Let me know how it goes per your requirement.

Comment: Yes thanks I will try this. For now the solution Karakuri provided solved my problem.